# Numer of permutations that are product of exactly two disjoint cycles

Tags: symmetric-groups

Let $a_n$ denote the number of those permutations $\sigma$ on $\{1,2,3....,n\}$ such that $\sigma$ is a product of exactly two disjoint cycles. Then

1. $a_5 = 50$
2. $a_4 = 14$
3. $a_5 = 40$
4. $a_4  = 11$

I tried specifically for $a_5$  and $a_4$ with a little bit of calculations. But I want to know about a formula for $a_n$ with less calculations

Comment: Why are lines 1 and 3 (and also lines 2 and 4) different?

Answer (score 4):

There's a well-known formula for the number of permutations with $p_i$ cycles of length $i$ for each $i$, namely

$$ {n! \over \prod_i i^{p_i} (p_i)!}$$

(see for example [this post by Mark Jason Dominus](http://blog.plover.com/math/fixpoints.html)).  In the case where you have one cycle of length $k$ and one of length $n-k$, and $k \not = n-k$, then you have $p_k = p_{n-k} = 1$ and this reduces to 
$$n! \times {1 \over k(n-k)}.$$  If $k = n-k$, that is, if $k = n/2$, then you have $p_k = 2$ and the number of such permutations is 
$$n! \times {2 \over n^2}.$$

For example, if $n = 5, k = 2$, the first formula gives you that there are $5!/(2 \times 3) = 20$ permutations of $[5]$ consisting of a 2-cycle and a 3-cycle.  If $n = 4, k = 2$, the second formula gives you that there are $4! \times 2/4^2 = 3$ permutations consisting of two 2-cycles.

From this you can derive a general formula for the number of permutations of $n$ which are products of two disjoint cycles by summing over the possible values of $k$. If $n$ is even you'll need to handle the $k = n/2$ case separately from the rest of the sum.

(It's not clear if your definition counts a cycle of length 1 as a cycle.  For example, is $(3, 5)(1, 4)(2)(6)$ a product of two distinct cycles in $S_6$?  If so your sum will be more complicated but the general idea still holds.)

Answer (score 1):

I would  like to present the  connection to Stirling numbers  since it
has  not been  pointed out.   For the  first interpretation  where the
cycles     may     be     singletons    we     get     the     species
$\mathfrak{P}_{=2}(\mathfrak{C}(\mathcal{Z}))$   which    yields   per
generating function

$$n! [z^n] \frac{1}{2!}\left(\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^2
= \left[n\atop 2\right]$$

the sequence

$$0, 1, 3, 11, 50, 274, 1764, 13068, 109584, 1026576,\ldots $$

which is [OEIS A000254](https://oeis.org/A000254)  which looks to be a
match. The second interpretation is when we do not admit singletons as
cycles  and we  get  the species  $\mathfrak{P}_{=2}(\mathfrak{C}_{\ge
2}(\mathcal{Z}))$ which yields per generating function

$$n! [z^n] \frac{1}{2!}\left(-z + \log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^2$$

the sequence

$$0, 0, 0, 3, 20, 130, 924, 7308, 64224, 623376,\ldots$$

which is  [OEIS A000276](https://oeis.org/A000276). For $n\ge  2$ this
simplifies to

$$\frac{1}{2} n! [z^n]
\left(z^2 - 2z \log\frac{1}{1-z} +
\left(\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^2\right)
\\ = [[n=2]] - n! [z^{n-1}] \log\frac{1}{1-z} + \left[n\atop 2\right]
\\ = [[n=2]] - n \times (n-2)! + \left[n\atop 2\right].$$

Comment: Very interesting but very above the level of this student, in particular due to the barrier of the combinatorics notations such as $\mathfrak{P}_{=2}(\mathfrak{C}(\mathcal{Z}))$ that at least deserve a reference for common people.

Comment: There is this entry at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_combinatorics).